# Is it possible to expand a xaml setter?

Tags: xaml

Is it possible for a XAML style to inherit from a style with the setter "template", inherit all existing triggers AND expand it with another trigger?

Example Style:

```
<Style x:Key="BigButton" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                <ControLTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Most of my Buttons have style with these two triggers.
So now to my question.
If I have following new Style:

```
<Style x:Key="BigButton" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}" 
  based on="{StaticResource BigButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType={x:Type RadioButton}">
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

With this style it overwrites the previous Template Setter.
So my question is:
Is there a way to NOT overwrite the previous Template Setter and only add the trigger in the new Style?

I hope you can help me.
If there are missing information please write it

Greetings
Richard

What I have tried:

Based On

Tried to get the triggers out of the controltemplate

Comment: Your examples are both missing a `</Setter>`

Comment: Thanks, I added them in the examples

Comment: The triggers are part of the ControlTemplate, so no, you can't just add them without overwriting the template. It's one of my biggest complains about XAML.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque if you create an answer I will upvode it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The triggers are part of the `ControlTemplate`, so no, you can't just add them without overwriting the template (which is a shame IMO, but that's the way it is).